# How to detect a point above and below a region?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have this image:

[image]

Where the red dots are coordinates that divide the different letters of this Arabic word segment.

I want to detect the dots above or below the areas between the dots.

The dots are (from left to right) = `[81,183;80,217;83,275;83,314]`

Now there is a dot above the letter between `[81,183]` and `[80,217]`. Similarly there are dots above section between `[80,217]` and `[83,275]` and dots below region `[83,275]` and `[83,314]`.

What I want to do is suppose a dot is detected above a coordinate then that coordinate must be deleted.
Would it be possible to detect these in Matlab?

edit: Here is the original image

[image]

The first image is just a crop showing my region of interest

Comment: Could you upload your original image somewhere and link it here? The one without the red encircled markers might be best. Asking for the original because the coordinates aren't matching when saving the image from here.

Comment: @Divakar You are right, sorry about that. I foolishly copied from the wrong matrix. I fixed the coordinates now and uploaded the original image

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the word mean?

Comment: It's written Argentine in Arabic. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the coordinates of the individual objects with `regionprops`
Here is an example implementation:

```
im=rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jic1X.jpg'));
P=regionprops(~im2bw(im), 'All');

Areas=cell2mat({P.Area});
Centroids=cell2mat({P.Centroid}');
```

Select only the points that have an area larger that 10 but smaller than 100:

```
Coord=Centroids(Areas< 100 & Areas > 10,:);
```

Monitor the dots found:

```
imshow(im);
hold on
for k=1:length(Coord)
    plot(Coord(k,1), Coord(k,2), 'ro');
    hold on
end
```

Result:

[image: Dots found]

You can then sort the points with something like:

```
Aboves=Coord(Coord(:,2) < 80,:);
Belows=Coord(Coord(:,2) > 80,:);
```

From here, there are many ways of solving your problem, one option is the following:

```
dots=[81,183;80,217;83,275;83,314];

DetectDots=zeros(length(dots)-1, 1); % Creating a vector of zeros corresponding to the gaps between the elements in 'dots' 
for k=1:size(dots,1)-1
    if ~isempty(find((Aboves(:,1) > dots(k,2) & Aboves(:,1) < dots(k+1,2)))) %*
        DetectDots(k)=1;
    elseif ~isempty(find((Belows(:,1) > dots(k,2) & Belows(:,1) < dots(k+1,2))))
        DetectDots(k)=-1;
    else
        DetectDots(k)=0;
    end

end
```

The result is a vector `DetectDots` with value `[1,1,-1]` in this case that indicates that there are dots above between the two first point, and between the second and third point, and dots below between the third and last point of the vector `dots`.

<sub>*`find` returns a logical array with ones where the condition is met. `isempty` checks if the output of `find` has at least one element. As a result the condition is one if there is at least one element in the array `Aboves` or `Belows` that meets the criteria. `~` is the logical NOT, hence `~=` means not equal. `&` is the logical AND. Note also that the coordinates between images and arrays are inverted in matlab.</sub>

Comment: You could also mention about how different dots (the upper and lower ones) could be detected to be in between which letters.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Curious though, shouldn't the comparison be done with codes? The comparison to be in between letters would be a bit complex.

Comment: @Divakar agreed, I don't have more time to invest at the moment, but if you write an answer with complementary information, you would surely get my vote.

Comment: I was just pointing out, because I guess ultimately someone would do it :) I will wait for OP to respond on the query. +1 For the efforts so far and an almost correct answer!

Comment: Thank you. So if I apply this code to my original image(uploaded in edit) Wont it find the centroids of every connected components? And is the aim to locate the dots like this? Then how would I differentiate between all? The first image was cropped because some dots are desirable like the left most and right most dot in the uncropped image. I only want to see if a dot exists above or below the regions between successive red dots that I labelled. ~Thank you

Comment: @Jigg Thank you but this is not exactly what I wanted to achieve. There are desirable dots in there. For example the left most and right most dots are of no interest to me. only the dots between my initial red circles are what i want to detect. Thats why I cropped the image. What I want to do is suppose a dot is detected above a coordinate then that coordinate must be deleted. I'm sorry but I think I was not clear in the initial question. I'll add this target there

Comment: @Jigg Thank you. That is what I was looking for. Can you please possibly comment your edited code. I seem to easily understand the code above the display of coords but below that I am a bit confused. Thank you again for your help

Comment: Thank you @Jigg. I understand the functions being used, not just the conditions. Can you please tell me whats going on in ``Aboves=Coord(Coord(:,2) < 80 & Coord(:,2) ~=0,:);`` I never knew ``~`` could be used in Matlab. And also in ``find((Aboves(:,1) > dots(k,2) & Aboves(:,1) < dots(k+1,2)))`` You mentioned find returns if this condition is met. it is this condition that I do not understand. Thank you for your help

Comment: @FarazKhan `~` is the logical NOT. Hence `~=` means not equal. The first selects elements of `Coord` that are non-zero and have a second coordinate smaller than 80. The second line returns ones when there is an element in `Above` that is between two points of the `dots` vector.  `&` is the logical AND.

Comment: @FarazKhan I admit that the first line was a bit confusing, I edited the code to make it more straightforward (I hope).