# Fingerprint Minutiae Marking Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fingerprint

I have a project on Fingerprint Matching. I binarized the image, thinned it and extracted the termination and bifurcation points. I stored the coordinates of these points into matrices (2 columns). The task I have to complete now is marking them on the image, and by marking I mean adding symbols (*,o,x) on those specific points.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at scatter and hold on?

Comment: Look at the third code chunk in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23201456/2777181